# Merge objects in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two arrays:

```
[{Name: "Jack", Depot: "5"}, {Name: "Jill", Depot: "6"}]
```

and

```
[{Depot Name: "Edgware"}, {Depot Name: "Romford"}]
```

I need to take the objects from the second array and merge them with the objects in the first array to produce a result of:

```
[{Name: "Jack", Depot: "5", Depot Name: "Edgware"}, {Name: "Jill", Depot: "6", Depot Name: "Romford"}]
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: firstly the key needs to be `'Depot Name'`

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: @BeeNag This is not a get code for free site. Please try it yourself first.

Comment: [`arr1.map((o, i) => Object.assign({}, o, arr2[i]))`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ut5s4z05/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
var array1 = [{
  Name: "Jack",
  Depot: "5"
}, {
  Name: "Jill",
  Depot: "6"
}];
var array2 = [{
  'Depot Name': "Edgware"
}, {
  'Depot Name': "Romford"
}];

for (var a in array1) {
  for (var p in array1[a]) {
    //to esclude all possible internal properties
    if (array1[a].hasOwnProperty(p)) {
  array2[a][p] = array1[a][p];
    }
  }
}

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Add an .hasOwnProperty() check to your solution and it's good.

Comment: Why? Explain me please.

Comment: There is the possibility of internal properties. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

**P.S:** Check for browser compatibility, this solution might not work in IE

```js
var arr1 = [{
  "Name": "Jack",
  "Depot": "5"
}, {
  "Name": "Jill",
  "Depot": "6"
}];

var arr2 = [{
  "Depot Name": "Edgware"
}, {
  "Depot Name": "Romford"
}];

var arr1Copy = arr1;
var newArr = arr1Copy.map(function(v, i) {
  return Object.assign(v, arr2[i]);
});

console.log(newArr);
```